# How to add a time stamp using ffmpeg to a screenshot capture of a video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture, thumbnails

I am trying to output a screenshot of a video at an specified time and the resulting picture should have a black square with the time that was given initially.

So far I was only able to produce a screenshot using vframes from the example at the documentation on ffmpeg page which is this below:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:00:14.435 -vframes 1 out.png
```

But I would like to add a timestamp in the resulting thumbnail or capture of the video which would show that '00:00:14.435' using arial fontface and a black square as background an yellow as fontcolor. Can this be done?.

Comment: See [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/19139/1871). Skip `\:1466507118`

Comment: I've already tried the method you mentioned but it does generate a sequence of frames and it is not the way how I intend to assess my problem hence i stressed the part of inserting the time in a black frame at the bottom of the screen capture with the specified time.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
ffmpeg -start_at_zero -copyts -ss 00:00:14.435 -i input.mp4
    -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/Arial.ttf:
          fontsize=45:fontcolor=yellow:box=1:boxcolor=black:x=(W-tw)/2:y=H-th-10:
          text='Time\: %{pts\:hms}'"
    -vframes 1 output.png
```

Comment: Can this code be expanded to take a screenshot every X minutes from the video and paste on each one the time elapsed until that point?. I am unable to do this by my own.